# Deleting product entity and keeping orders intact in java spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, cascading-deletes

In a java spring boot application i have Product, OrderDetail and Order entities, so i have a many to many between Product and Order through OrderDetail. How can i delete products and still keep the OrderDetail intact? i was thinking about implementing a soft delete but i think that i should modify the deletion methods on the whole project( and i have many entities related to the Product entity), so i would like to keep the phisical deletion. If this is not really ok, then i would like to hear any suggestions.

These are the entities

```
@Table
@Builder
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

 <<Other relationships>>>
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OrderDetail {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Orders order;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;
<<Other fields>>
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Orders{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserInfo user;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<OrderDetail> orderDetails = new ArrayList<>();

<<other fields>>
}
```

Comment: Create an OrderProduct table to keep the Products of an order.  As you've noted, an order has to maintain all of its details at the time the order was placed or fulfilled.